# Intercept incoming message of Spring Cloud Stream SubscribableChannel

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream, spring-messaging

Since method `postReceive` of `org.springframework.messaging.support.ChannelInterceptor` is not invoked in `org.springframework.messaging.SubscribableChannel`. Is there any way to intercept all of incoming messages for method annotated`@StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)`?

For example:

Intercept the message before go into `handle` method

```
@StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
public void handle(Foo foo) {
    // ...
}
```

Below is my setup for Spring Cloud Stream

```
public interface EventSink {

    String INPUT1 = "input1";
    String INPUT2 = "input2";

    @Input(INPUT1)
    SubscribableChannel input1();

    @Input(INPUT2)
    SubscribableChannel input2();   
}

public interface EventSource {

    String OUTPUT1 = "output1";
    String OUTPUT2 = "output2";

    @Output(OUTPUT1)
    MessageChannel output1();

    @Output(OUTPUT2)
    MessageChannel output2()';
}

spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input1:
          destination: input1
        input2:
          destination: input2     
        output1:
          destination: output1
        output2:
          destination: output2

public class EventHandler {

    @StreamListener(EventSink.INPUT1)
    public void handle(Foo1 foo) {
        // ...
    }

    @StreamListener(EventSink.INPUT2)
    public void handle(Foo2 foo) {
        // ...
    }

}

@Service
public class Bar1Service {

    @Autowired
    private EventSource source;

    public void bar1() {
        source.output1().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("bar1").build());
    }

}

@Service
public class Bar2Service {

    @Autowired
    private EventSource source;

    public void bar2() {
        source.output2().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("bar2").build());
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you want to do in the interceptor? You can intercept `preSend()`.

Comment: I would like to extract and prepare some information from headers and store them into ThreadLocal. I thought `preSend` is for output.

Comment: `preSend()` is appropriate - but see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WIth a `DirectChannel` the binder invokes your listener on the same thread so `preSend` is appropriate here.

However, you don't have to mess with `ThreadLocal`, you can access headers using the method signature...

```
@StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)
public void handle(Foo foo, @Header("bar") String bar) {
    ...
}
```

**EDIT**

```
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
public class So41459187Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So41459187Application.class, args);
    }

    @StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)
    @SendTo(Processor.OUTPUT)
    public String handle(String in) {
        return in.toUpperCase();
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class Config {

        @Bean
        public BeanPostProcessor channelConfigurer() {
            return new BeanPostProcessor() {

                @Override
                public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
                    return bean;
                }

                @Override
                public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
                    if ("input".equals(beanName)) {
                        ((AbstractMessageChannel) bean).addInterceptor(new ChannelInterceptorAdapter() {

                            @Override
                            public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
                                System.out.println("PreSend on INPUT: " + message);
                                return message;
                            }

                        });
                    }
                    else if ("output".equals(beanName)) {
                        ((AbstractMessageChannel) bean).addInterceptor(new ChannelInterceptorAdapter() {

                            @Override
                            public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
                                System.out.println("PreSend on OUTPUT: " + message);
                                return message;
                            }

                        });
                    }
                    return bean;
                }

            };
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, appreciated it! I am using `ThreadLocal` is because there are several `handle` methods listening on different channels, so I was looking for a global way to retrieve information from headers for all `handle` methods. So that I don't have to put `@Headers` or `MessageHeaders` on every of `handle` methods.

Comment: And I have confirmed that `preSend` is appropriate. (Thanks again)
But I am confused now. Both inbound and outbound channels will invoke `preSend` method. For inbound channel I have to extract information from headers and for outbound channel I need to set information in the headers to pass to consumers. How can I separate these two businesses?

Comment: Or maybe I can config different interceptors for producer and consumer on bindings?

Comment: Yes, you simply need to configure a different interceptor on each channel.

Comment: Could you show me how can I do this in spring cloud stream? Since channel is auto generated in spring cloud stream and I cannot find a way to configure about this.

Comment: How are you currently configuring your interceptor?

Comment: There are several ways to do it; I edited my answer with one of them.

Comment: I am using `@GlobalChannelInterceptor` right now, cause I did not find a way to config interceptor. I have updated my setup for spring cloud stream in the question above.

Comment: When using global interceptors you can simply use the `patterns` property to determine which channel name(s) the interceptor is applied to.

Comment: Thank you! Both solutions are perfect!

Comment: @user1831877 Can you share how the code looks like? i have a similar use case where i need to process headers for Messages coming into my SubscribableChannel and set a thread local.

Comment: @GaryRussell Isnt the additional check for each bean name an overhead? Is there any alternate way of doing this through AOP; I found this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50682722/spring-boot-2-0-2-interception-of-cloud-stream-annotations-with-aop-not-working; However the ChannelInterceptorManager doesnt seem to be available in spring cloud stream 3.0.1. Please advise

Comment: The bean post processor `postProcessAfterInitialization()` only runs once, during initialization to add the interceptors one time only. This is more efficient than AOP.