# Spring boot 2.0.2, interception of Cloud Stream annotations with Aop not working anymore

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop, spring-cloud-stream

I tried to keep the title as explicit and simple as possible.

Basically, I need to intercept the usage of Cloud stream's @Input and @Output annotations. This is needed to automatically add a specific ChannelInterceptor to each MessageChannel. (The behaviour in the preSend method will be slightly different whether the message has been produced or consumed).

For example, if I declare this advice

```
@Around("@annotation(org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Input)")
public Object interceptInput(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    LOG.debug("Intercepted @Input from method : {}", joinPoint.getSignature());

    Object returnValue = null;

    try {
        returnValue = joinPoint.proceed();
ChannelInterceptorManager.addInputInterceptor((AbstractMessageChannel)returnValue);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.warn("@Input error", e);
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

and I declare this example class

```
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
@Component
public class MyClass {

    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
   public void handle(Object message) {
      // preSend has been called before this method
   }
}
```

This worked perfectly fine with Spring Boot 2.0.1, but not with Spring Boot 2.0.2 and I'm struggling to understand why.

I haven't tried other Cloud stream's annotations, but basic Aop works fine.

Keep in mind that this is meant to be used in a JAR, as such I don't know in advance the classes or the channel names which will be used, I need this to be automatic and transparent to the developer.

Thanks !

Edit : In case anyone reading this isn't familiar with Cloud stream, the Sink interface declares a method annotated with @Input, so enabling binding on it will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, BPP doesn't fully solve the issue, as I need to differentiate MessageChannel created with @Input from those created with @Output. The MessageChannel bean does not carry this information. This is why I used Aop in the first place, to intercept those two annotations separately.

For insight : I have also thought of using @GlobalChannelInterceptor with patterns containing either "input" or "output", but that would mean enforcing such patterns to the end user. I'm keeping this solution as last resort, but I would like this process to be completely invisible and impact-less while using the jar. This is where AOP came in handy, but this new behaviour from 2.0.2 is certainly problematic in my case.

Edit : So the issue with the version change is the bean initialization order, for anyone having a similar issue with Spring boot 2.0.2. If you have control over each bean you need, I suggest you take a look at @DependsOn.

Ultimately, I solved my specific issue by using BeanPostProcessor instead of AOP to separate inputs from outputs, as suggested by @Oleg Zhurakousky.
Below is a working method :

```
@Autowired
    private AbstractBeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof AbstractMessageChannel) {
            try {
                RootBeanDefinition beanDefinition = (RootBeanDefinition) beanFactory.getMergedBeanDefinition(beanName);
                Method method = beanDefinition.getResolvedFactoryMethod();

                if (method != null) {
                    if (AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(method, Input.class) != null) {
                        ((AbstractMessageChannel)bean).addInterceptor(/*Your input ChannelInterceptor*/);
                    } else if (AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(method, Output.class) != null) {
                        ((AbstractMessageChannel)bean).addInterceptor(/*Your output ChannelInterceptor*/);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // exception can be thrown by the bean factory
            }
        }

        return bean;
    }
```

Comment: I am not following. Channels would have names. Can't you use that? The bottom line your AOP approach (although indirectly) was relying on order of bean creation which is not something you should ever take for granted especially if you're dealing with beans you do not control.
The BPP approach or even InitializingBean allows you access to the AC before application starts, access any bean you want and perform additional post processing on it, regardless of the order.

Comment: I get the point, however ideally the end-user should be free to name the channels however he wants. If he calls a channel "topicInput" then it's fine, but he could also call it "topic", but I'd still need to intercept it as an input channel. 
The issue with BPP is that I can't have this information since its type (MessageChannel is the interface) doesn't carry it as far as I know, and I can't trust the bean's name either.

I'm completely open to a solution other than AOP and that'd actually be better, but I have yet to find one :/

Comment: Well, you can get the annotation information if you really want to. But before we go there, input channels are PublishSubscribeChannels while output are typically DirectChannels. That may be all you need

Comment: I have tried BPP, and in both cases the beans are of type DirectChannel. Inputs will not be PublishSubscribeChannel either, since currently it is planned to be used with Kafka.

Comment: I forgot to respond to "you can get the annotation information if you really want to", how so ? If you refer to the Sink javadoc ( http://static.javadoc.io/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-stream/1.2.2.RELEASE/org/springframework/cloud/stream/messaging/Sink.html ), the method input() returns the MessageChannel bean which I need to add the interceptor on. However, the channel isn't annotated, the method input() is.

Comment: You can try do the following:
```
      RootBeanDefinition beanDefinition = (RootBeanDefinition) beanFactory.getMergedBeanDefinition(beanName);
     Method method = beanDefinition.getResolvedFactoryMethod();
```
. . . and then use AnnotationUtils to introspect the method ( which is factory method) and get its annotation

Comment: Look at the BindableProxyFactory for reference.
All that said, I am still wondering if what you are trying to accomplish can be done differently. Perhaps you can share your business case, rather then discussing specific solution which may not be the most appropriate one

Comment: Your solution works perfectly, thanks a lot !

As for the business case, we are planning to add support of Spring Cloud Stream to publish and consumes messages on kafka in the company, between applications. The goal is to promote the usage of Cloud stream as it is documented, but we want to restrict the message's format with various meta-datas.  What I'm trying to do is adding those meta-datas when producing a message, and validating a message on consumption, before it is handled any further and reject it if the meta-datas are missing.

Comment: Implementation-wise before making this post, I had 2 ChannelInterceptor, one for Inputs and one for Outputs. But since I don't know in advance which channels are going to be used at all, the only solution I had found was to intercept the initial binding with AOP and add the corresponding interceptor to the newly binded MessageChannel.

Comment: @SébastienPalud Can you post a sample of how you used AOP for intercepting the binding. I have tried doing this myself but cant advise the method annotated with StreamListener for message consumption

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what happened between boot 2.0.1 and 2.0.2, but the above sounds like a pretty complex way of doing something simple. Why not just register BPP where you can add pre/post channel interceptors during initialization time.

Comment: The difference is the order in which the beans are created; in 2.0.1, the `@Aspect` is created before the `Sink`; in 2.0.2 it's the other way around, so the aspect is created too late.

Comment: I thought of that but I had no way of asserting if that was the case or not, thanks for confirming ! Do you perhaps have any way of ensuring that the @Aspect is created early during beans initialization ? I'll give a look at BPP tomorrow,